# pure ftpd : how to set owner on files uploaded

Tags: debian, pure-ftpd

I have a debian with pure ftpd installed with virtual users.

I used the documentation for my setup so the local account of pure ftpd is ftpuser:ftpgroup
When a user uploads a file, the file is owned by ftpuser:ftpgroup. I want the uploaded file to be owned by another system user (mylocaluser). I added my virtual user this way :

```
pure-pw useradd uploadimages -u mylocaluser -d /var/www/mysite/current/images
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure-FTPD has something like `MYSQLGetUID` and `MYSQLGetGID` for specifying queries to get UID/GID. Depending on your mysql table you can use something like this:

```
MYSQLGetUID    SELECT Uid FROM ftpd WHERE User="\L" AND status="1"
MYSQLGetGID    SELECT Gid FROM ftpd WHERE User="\L" AND status="1"
```

under the `MYSQLGetPW` query definition. More info in documentation fo Pure-FTPD, section [MySQL authentication](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.MySQL)

---

OK, my bad I didn't read carefully that you're using PureDB to store users. After you create user you can modify it's info like this:

```
pure-pw usermod uploadimages -u UID -g GID
```

then check with `pure-pw show uploadimages` if the UID/GID are correct.

Comment: Thks! I was using -u mylocaluser and it seems to work better with the UID. OR maybe you have to provide a group GID too.